# Does a weak flame invalidate Hanuka candles?

Tags: halacha, chanuka, fire-burning

[I was asked to post this question by a user who doesn't have access to MY]

According to the [OU website](https://www.ou.org/holidays/chanukah/point-flame-no-longer-flame/)

> The Beis Ha Levi rules that once the flame is dark and is going out,
>   it is already as if it is totally doused and there is no more mitzvah
>   even though there is still a flame there; the reason being that such a
>   flame has no beauty and is not at all recognizable as being for the
>   mitzvah. (What this is most probably referring to is when there is
>   only a blue light coming out of the candle, without any yellow or
>   orange).

Does this mean that, at least according to the Beis HaLevi, if the Chanukah candles must last for 30 minutes, but during the last minute of the 30 minutes the flame is weak like he describes, is the person not yotzei the mitzvah? Do any later authorities rule like this Beis HaLevi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Halacha is *kovsa ain zukkuk luh* (if the candle goes out you are not responsible). As long as you put in enough fuel to last for 1/2 hour (without becoming weak, according to Beis HaLevi) you have discharged your obligation and need not be concerned with unforeseeable circumstances ([SA Orach Chaim 673:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.673.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Comment: Thanks for adding the link. How do you do that?

Comment: In edit mode, select the piece of text to link and press Ctrl-L (Command-L on a Mac) or click the link icon (third from left) in bar above text box

Comment: full help for edit box: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/editing-help